# Is there any way to use regular expression in NO_PROXY environment variable?

Tags: python, kubernetes, python-requests, proxy

I want to bypass proxy for domains like:

```
http://server-1:5000
http://server-2:5000
```

`NO_PROXY=server-1, server-2`

server-1 and server-2 are basically services attached to kube pods, so they can change dynamically during runtime.

I want to bypass proxy for any domains in this format. For example, at any point it can even reach to `server-124`.

It would have been easier if domain name was in this format : `subdomain.domain.com`
like `1.server.com` , `2.server.com`.

I believe, `NO_PROXY=.server.com` would have worked in this case.

But my current scenario is a little different. So, can it be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done. `NO_PROXY=*.server.*`

This will help to bypass proxy for any domain like .server. or server-124.
This wild card match will handle that.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, setting `no_proxy` to `*` effectively disables proxies altogether, but this is not a universal rule.

No implementation performs a DNS lookup to resolve a hostname to an IP address when deciding if a proxy should be used. Do not specify IP addresses in the `no_proxy` variable unless you expect that the IPs are explicitly used by the client.

The same holds true for CIDR blocks, such as `18.240.0.1/24`. CIDR blocks only work when the request is directly made to an IP address.

The libraries that support the `http_proxy` environment variable generally also support a matching `no_proxy` that names things that shouldn't be proxied. The exact syntax seems to [vary across languages and libraries](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/01/27/we-need-to-talk-no-proxy/#no_proxy) but it does seem to be universal that setting `no_proxy=example.com` causes `anything.example.com` to not be proxied either.

This is relevant because the [Kubernetes DNS system](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#dns-records) creates its names in a domain based on the cluster name, by default `cluster.local`. The canonical form of a Service DNS name, for example, is `service-name.namespace-name.svc.cluster.local.`, where `service-name` and `namespace-name` are the names of the corresponding Kubernetes objects.